# Modifying value of ntext column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ntext

I have a column in ntext which holds large unicode strings longer than 4000 chars in length. I need to update/modify the data of the rows of the column in sql but I have no clue how to do so. I have tried nvarchar(max) as a buffer but it truncates the data into 4000 chars.

Could anyone help me give me a hint or an idea or a workround solution, because I'm really lost in this one?

Comment: Show us the code that is truncating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nvarchar(max) does not truncate.

You have an intermediate nvarchar(4000) (or shorter) somewhere, usually  a string constant. See my answer for more info: [For Nvarchar(Max) I am only getting 4000 characters in TSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371383/for-nvarcharmax-i-am-only-getting-4000-characters-in-tsql/1371584#1371584)

If you can cast to nvarchar(max), then it means you can change your columns too... As Remus said, ntext is deprecated.

Comment: I have tested with nvarchar(max), and it works fine. There must be some intermediate variable causing the prob in the proc.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the obsolete type NTEXT with the more appropriate NVARCHAR(MAX) and use the UPDATE SET column.Write syntax, see [Using Large-Value Data Types](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178158.aspx).

The old type NTEXT supports the [UPDATETEXT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189466.aspx), but is obsolete now.