# My VARCHAR(MAX) field is capping itself at 4000; what gives?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, varchar, varcharmax

I have a table in one of my databases which is a queue of emails. Emails to certain addresses get accumulated into one email, which is done by a sproc. In the sproc, I have a table variable which I use to build the accumulated bodies of the emails, and then loop through to send each email. In my table var I have my body column defined as `VARCHAR(MAX)`, seeing as there could be any number of emails currently accumulated for a given email address. It seems though that even though my column is defined as `VARCHAR(MAX)` it is behaving as if it were `VARCHAR(4000)` and is truncating the data going into it, although it does **NOT** throw any exceptions, it just silently stops concatenating any more data after 4000 characters.

The MERGE statement is where it is building the accumulated email body into @EMAILS.BODY, which is the field that is truncating itself at 4000 characters.

**EDIT**

I have updated my MERGE statement in an attempt to cast the whole assigned string to VARCHAR(MAX), but it is still silently truncating itself to 4000 chars... here is my new MERGE:

```
MERGE @EMAILS AS DST 
USING (SELECT * FROM @ROWS WHERE ROWID = @CURRID) AS SRC 
ON SRC.ADDRESS = DST.ADDRESS 
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET 
        DST.ALLIDS = DST.ALLIDS + ', ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,ROWID), 
        DST.BODY = DST.BODY + 
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),
                '<i>'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,SRC.DATED,101)+
                ' '+CONVERT(VARCHAR,SRC.DATED,8)+
                ':</i> <b>'+SRC.SUBJECT+'</b>'+CHAR(13)+
                SRC.BODY+' (Message ID '+
                CONVERT(VARCHAR,SRC.ROWID)+')'+
                CHAR(13)+CHAR(13)
            )
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
    INSERT (ADDRESS, ALLIDS, BODY) VALUES (
        SRC.ADDRESS, 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR,ROWID), 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),
            '<i>'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,SRC.DATED,101)+
            ' '+CONVERT(VARCHAR,SRC.DATED,8)+
            ':</i> <b>'+SRC.SUBJECT+'</b>'+CHAR(13)+
            SRC.BODY+' (Message ID '+CONVERT(VARCHAR,SRC.ROWID)+')'
            +CHAR(13)+CHAR(13)
        )
    );
```

**END EDIT**

Below is the code of my sproc...

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [system].[SendAccumulatedEmails]
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @SENTS  BIGINT = 0;

    DECLARE @ROWS TABLE (
        ROWID    ROWID, 
        DATED    DATETIME, 
        ADDRESS  NAME, 
        SUBJECT  VARCHAR(1000), 
        BODY     VARCHAR(MAX)
    )
    INSERT INTO @ROWS SELECT ROWID, DATED, ADDRESS, SUBJECT, BODY 
    FROM system.EMAILQUEUE 
        WHERE ACCUMULATE = 1 AND SENT IS NULL
        ORDER BY ADDRESS, DATED

    DECLARE @EMAILS TABLE (
        ADDRESS  NAME, 
        ALLIDS   VARCHAR(1000),
        BODY     VARCHAR(MAX) 
    )

    DECLARE @PRVRID ROWID = NULL, @CURRID ROWID = NULL
    SELECT @CURRID = MIN(ROWID) FROM @ROWS
    WHILE @CURRID IS NOT NULL BEGIN
        MERGE @EMAILS AS DST 
        USING (SELECT * FROM @ROWS WHERE ROWID = @CURRID) AS SRC 
        ON SRC.ADDRESS = DST.ADDRESS 
        WHEN MATCHED THEN 
            UPDATE SET 
                DST.ALLIDS = DST.ALLIDS + ', ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,ROWID), 
                DST.BODY = DST.BODY + '<i>'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,SRC.DATED,101)+' '
                            +CONVERT(VARCHAR,SRC.DATED,8)
                            +':</i> <b>'+SRC.SUBJECT+'</b>'+CHAR(13)+SRC.BODY
                            +' (Message ID '+CONVERT(VARCHAR,SRC.ROWID)+')'
                            +CHAR(13)+CHAR(13)
        WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
            INSERT (ADDRESS, ALLIDS, BODY) VALUES (
                SRC.ADDRESS, 
                CONVERT(VARCHAR,ROWID), 
                '<i>'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,SRC.DATED,101)+' '
                    +CONVERT(VARCHAR,SRC.DATED,8)+':</i> <b>'
                    +SRC.SUBJECT+'</b>'+CHAR(13)+SRC.BODY
                    +' (Message ID '+CONVERT(VARCHAR,SRC.ROWID)+')'
                    +CHAR(13)+CHAR(13));

        SELECT @PRVRID = @CURRID, @CURRID = NULL
        SELECT @CURRID = MIN(ROWID) FROM @ROWS WHERE ROWID > @PRVRID
    END 

    DECLARE @MAILFROM VARCHAR(100) = system.getOption('MAILFROM'), 
    DECLARE @SMTPHST VARCHAR(100) = system.getOption('SMTPSERVER'), 
    DECLARE @SMTPUSR VARCHAR(100) = system.getOption('SMTPUSER'), 
    DECLARE @SMTPPWD VARCHAR(100) = system.getOption('SMTPPASS')

    DECLARE @ADDRESS NAME, @BODY VARCHAR(MAX), @ADDL VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @SUBJECT VARCHAR(1000) = 'Accumulated Emails from LIJSL'

    DECLARE @PRVID NAME = NULL, @CURID NAME = NULL 
    SELECT @CURID = MIN(ADDRESS) FROM @EMAILS
    WHILE @CURID IS NOT NULL BEGIN
        SELECT @ADDRESS = ADDRESS, @BODY = BODY 
        FROM @EMAILS WHERE ADDRESS = @CURID

        SELECT @BODY = @BODY + 'This is an automated message sent from an unmonitored mailbox.'+CHAR(13)+'Do not reply to this message; your message will not be read.'
        SELECT @BODY = 
            '<style type="text/css">
                * {font-family: Tahoma, Arial, Verdana;}
                p {margin-top: 10px; padding-top: 10px; border-top: single 1px dimgray;} 
                p:first-child {margin-top: 10px; padding-top: 0px; border-top: none 0px transparent;}
            </style>' 
            + @BODY 

        exec system.LogIt @SUBJECT, @BODY

        BEGIN TRY 
            exec system.SendMail @SMTPHST, @SMTPUSR, @SMTPPWD, @MAILFROM, 
                             @ADDRESS, NULL, NULL, @SUBJECT, @BODY, 1
        END TRY 
        BEGIN CATCH
            DECLARE @EMSG NVARCHAR(2048) = 'system.EMAILQUEUE.AI:'+ERROR_MESSAGE()
            SELECT @ADDL = 'TO:'+@ADDRESS+CHAR(13)+'SUBJECT:'+@SUBJECT+CHAR(13)+'BODY:'+@BODY
            exec system.LogIt @EMSG,@ADDL
        END CATCH

        SELECT @PRVID = @CURID, @CURID = NULL
        SELECT @CURID = MIN(ADDRESS) FROM @EMAILS WHERE ADDRESS > @PRVID
    END

    UPDATE system.EMAILQUEUE SET SENT = getdate()
    FROM system.EMAILQUEUE E, @ROWS R WHERE E.ROWID = R.ROWID
END
```

Comment: Please see my update... you have an nvarchar on the right which is casting from varchar(max) to nvarchar(4000) implicitly

Comment: Would wrapping the whole RHS expression in a CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), <expression>) as per my update not take care of this?

Comment: The only thing I see that is not explicitly converted to VARCHAR(MAX) is the literal strings such as '<i>'. Do literals go in as NVARCHAR? The SRC.<fields> are all converted to VARCHAR, and the CHAR function returns a CHAR type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gbn and Jeffrey, thank you for you help, you got me going in the right direction. Though after some logging and checking, it actually is concatenating my string just fine.

The problem was not with my column datatype or length, but with the call to my .NET `SendMail` procedure, which is only accepting NVARCHAR(4000) for the BODY argument... the apparent translation of the .NET `SqlString` type.

So now I am off on a hunt to figure how to pass longer strings into a CLR assembly function.

Comment: FYI to any interested... passing an NVARCHAR(MAX) field into a CLR sproc is done by decorating the specific parameter with the attribute <SqlFacet(MaxSize:=-1)>

Comment: So you didn't actually know that that data in the table was OK? You never though to do LEN on it? So the question is wrong and misleading...

Comment: I had figured, obviously incorrectly, that it had to be a problem with the T-SQL code. I hadn't thought of looking at the .NET code because when it comes to .NET I'm used to dealing with just Strings, where there is no concern with length. I have not done a lot of .NET/CLR-SQL integration, and so didn't think to look there. We've all had days where we've missed the obvious for it staring us in the face and needed a fresh set of eyes to help point us in the right direction.

Answer (score 5):

Corrected...

The table may by varchar(max) but the values you assign are only **nvarchar**(4000)

That is,

```
maxcolumn = maxvalues + smallstring1 + **unicodestring** + smallstring3 + smallstring4 ...
```

The right hand side will stay at nvarchar(4000) *maximum* because of [datatype precedence.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) nvarchar > varchar. When assigned to the max column it truncates

You'll have to ensure all values on the right at varchar

It's *still* like integer division... what confused me was the 4000 limit when varchar is 8000... this implies nvarchar somewhere.

[For Nvarchar(Max) I am only getting 4000 characters in TSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371383/for-nvarcharmax-i-am-only-getting-4000-characters-in-tsql/1371584#1371584)

Comment: Well, in the MERGE statement, it is setting DST.BODY = DST.BODY + <smallstrings>. Since DST.BODY is on the right hand side, and is defined VARCHAR(MAX), wouldn't that fulfill this?

Comment: @eidylon: what about the INSERT...?

Comment: @gbn - SRC.BODY should promote the entire expression to MAX, if I'm reading MSDN correctly.

Comment: My UPDATE now does DST.BODY = DST.BODY + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),<smallstrings>) and the INSERT likewise inserts CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),<smallstrings>) to DST.BODY, but it is still truncating.

Comment: "If the result of the concatenation of strings exceeds the limit of 8,000 bytes, the result is truncated. However, if at least one of the strings concatenated is a large value type, truncation does not occur."

Comment: @Jeffrey - hmmmm, then I would think my code should work. The INSERT case assertively never inserts more than about 400 characters, and in the case of the UPDATE, one of the concatenated strings (namely DST.BODY on the RHS) is a large type.

Comment: @Jeffrey L Whitledge, @eidylon: OK, I was partially correct... updated now

Comment: The real lesson here is that varchar(max) *generally appears* to behave like varchar, but sometimes behaves like a totally different data type. Concatenation is one of those times. AFAIK, you always have to specify varchar(max) on converts if that's what you're after.

Comment: I looked for a precedence problem with NVARCHAR, but I missed it. I guess I shouldn't rely on my eyes for searching text strings!

Comment: @eidylon - The solution, as always, is to use Unicode for *everything*! I haven't used an 8-bit codepage in years, and I'll never look back! :-)

Answer (score 3):

http://blogs.infosupport.com/blogs/marks/archive/2011/03/22/take-your-varchar-to-the-max.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage

This problem and solution to it are very well explained in the above article, the solution is to add to the concatenation a VARCHAR(MAX)

AS IN

DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = ''
SET @SQL = @SQL + 'xxxxxx(n)'

Comment: Who would have believed! What a strange behavior! Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem lies in the string and conversion operations.  Try changing your conversions to VARCHAR(max) or converting the entire expression to VARCHAR(max).

Comment: Okay, I tried wrapping the entire expression being assigned/concatenated to DST.BODY to max as CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),<bodyExpression>) and it is still silently truncating anything past 4000.