# varchar(max) + linq to sql

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, varchar

I've got a varchar(max) column I'm trying to read but the field is being truncated at 4,000 characters.  I've seen [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502734/my-varcharmax-field-is-capping-itself-at-4000-what-gives), but they are on the sql side.

What do I need to do to get the entire field?

Eg:

```
using (DataContext dc = new DataContext())
{
    var foo = dc.foos.First();
    if (foo.Formula2.Length > 4000)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("success!");
    }
}
```

I've tried things like [setting TextSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186238.aspx) but it didn't make a difference.:

```
dc.ExecuteCommand("SET TEXTSIZE 100000;");
var foo = dc.foos.First();
```

**UPDATE:**

The server data type is varchar(max).  The field in question is formula2:
[image]

If I try and change the type to something different like Object, I get message '*Mapping between DbType 'VarChar(MAX)' and Type 'System.Object' in Column 'Formula2' of Type 't_PriceFormula' is not supported.*'

Any suggestions?

Comment: How is the column configured in the DBML? in particular the `Server Data Type` property?

Comment: What is the compatibility level of the database server? see here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [thanks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809109/varcharmax-linq-to-sql/3913651#3913651) to [888](https://stackoverflow.com/users/471007/888).

This seems a little convoluted but it worked.

Convert the field to an array, then back to a string.

```
var foo = dc.foos.First();
string formula = new string(foo.Formula2.ToArray());
```

Comment: Isn't this 888's answer?  Shouldn't you award it to them?

Comment: 888's suggestion was to convert the field to varbinary(max).  I upvoted and used that to get my response.

Answer (score 2):

sounds like .net convert varchar to nvarchar
i dont know how to directly solve it. but System.Text.Encoding might help
try this

```
//1 set col in db to varbinary(max)

//2 and when u want to save to db
string formula = "...";
System.Data.Linq.Binary bin = new System.Data.Linq.Binary(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes());

//3 when u pull ou
    Binary bin = row.Formula2;
    string formula = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bin.ToArray());
```

Comment: Converting the field to varbinary is extreme.  If the database supports the field then there must be a way to get it out...