# sql varchar(max) issue

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am using SQL Server 2005 as the back - end for my application. I have given the datatype varchar(max) for a particular column but its storing only 1000 characters. Why is it like that.

Comment: Does SQL 2005 even support `varchar(max)`?

Comment: Yes leppie it has a datatype called Varchar(MAX), i dont have any idea whether it supports or not.

Comment: How do you know that it stores only 1000 characters?? How are you interacting with the database - Mgmt Studio? Your own app?? Could it be that your app somehow limits the size of the string to 1'000 chars??

Comment: @leppie Yes, it does. It was introduced to replace the text datatype, which is by now declared deprecated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its support varchar(max) and it can store more than 1000 character.

I think Mathew you have given the range in insert or update query for this table.

might be in the stored procedure or query you have define the limitations.

Comment: Thank you Bhavik earlier in my db it was 1000 but after some days admin changed the db size to max but it was not implemented in my stored procedure any way thank you for your valuable reply

Answer (score 2):

Random thought: [Your intermediate datatypes/conversions are not varchar(max)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502734/my-varcharmax-field-is-capping-itself-at-4000-what-gives/2502767#2502767)