# sending automatic mail sql jobs procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, job-scheduling

i have created an sql job for sending mails daily.. 
i am using HTML table for the report to display. and everything is working fine..if the data exceeds 8000 characters my table is getting truncated.. i tried nvarchar(max) still the table is getting truncated..

how to solve this issue..plz help me out

can i save the result in an excel sheet and attach the same in the mail so that i can overcome the word limit problm..
could you help me out to give some sample codes to how to save the result in an excel sheet and attach the same xcel sheet...

thnx 
navin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if the target column is (max), the expression you are assigning to the column will be 8000 max. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371383/for-nvarcharmax-i-am-only-getting-4000-characters-in-tsql/1371584#1371584) for a worked example