# Make sp_executesql take varchar instead of nvarchar?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a very long inline query that even when i set the nvarchar property to MAX the text gets truncated. Is there any way to make the sp_executesql to take a varchar instead.

When i try to change the nvarchar to varchar, i get an error, i have tried ntext too but same results.

Edit:

Based what i read on the question that were posted on the answer, this should work but it dosen't can anybody tell me why ?

```
    Declare @X varchar(MAX)
    SET @X = N'Select * From Users'
    Execute sp_executesql @X
```

While this works with no problems:

```
    Execute sp_executesql N'Select * From Users'
```

Comment: Same user as this? http://stackoverflow.com/q/14828534/27535

Comment: `@X` has to be `nvarchar(max)`. Like this `Declare @X nvarchar(MAX)`.

Comment: the idea is putting the 'N' before the statement should make it work, that is what i understood event if it's varchar.

Comment: Nope. If you use a variable it has to be `nvarchar`. Your concatenating issues (truncation) could be fixed by using `@X = cast('' as nvarchar(max)) + N'select ' + etc `. The first cast on an empty string make sure that the concatenated string is `max`.

Answer (score 1):

No. `sp_executesql` requires nvarchar for the @stmt and @params parameters

*Your* parameters do not have to be nvarchar.

See [Call sp_executesql with varchar parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14828534/call-sp-executesql-with-varchar-parameter/14828575#14828575)

If your nvarchar(max) is being truncated, you are concatenating wrong.
See [For Nvarchar(Max) I am only getting 4000 characters in TSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371383/for-nvarcharmax-i-am-only-getting-4000-characters-in-tsql/1371584#1371584) for why

The point of sp_executesql is to avoid string building anyway: it allows you parametrise fixed queries for execution plan re-use. Why do you concatenate to build a string?

Comment: Its a dynamic query, which join different strings together such as where and order by...etc.