# Call sp_executesql with varchar parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I faced problem when I called `sp_executesql` and I passed varchar parameter.
I got this error:

> Procedure expects parameter '@statement' of type
>   'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.

Answer (score 1):

Psychic debugger says you either are passing to `SP_ExecuteSQL` a variable of type varchar (make it nvarchar), or you've got a string you haven't used the unicode prefix on:

E.g.

```
Exec sp_executesql 'select * from something'
```

To fix it use:

```
Exec sp_executesql N'select * from something'
```

Notice the `N` prefix on the string.

Comment: I construct the @SQL as varchar parameter then pass it to sp_executesql.

Comment: Then I've told you how to fix it - declare it as an `nvarchar` parameter of appropriate length (if greater than 4000 characters needed, use `nvarchar(max)`).

Comment: i did this and the same, the @SQL trimmed and can't contain all the dynamic query i built.

Comment: Does it work with `Exec` directly rather than using `sp_executesql` (should be easy to test if you aren't using parameters). Also, why not split your script into batches? I doubt it _needs_ to be that long.

Answer (score 0):

This means the `@statement` parameter of `sp_executesql` expects `nvarchar`.

This does **not** mean that *your* parameter has to be nvarchar.
Of course, if you don't have parameters, why are you using sp_executesql?

```
CREATE TABLE #foo (bar varchar(100) NOT NULL);
DECLARE @filter varchar(100) = 'bob';
EXEC sys.sp_executesql
      N'SELECT * FROM #foo WHERE bar = @p1', --NVARCHAR because of N prefix
      N'@p1 varchar(100)', --NVARCHAR because of N prefix
      @filter --VARCHAR
DROP TABLE #foo
```

Comment: i am building a dynamic query where the fields change.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

e.g. This will give the error because @SQL needs to be NVARCHAR

Below give error:

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(100)
SET @SQL = 'SELECT TOP 1 * FROM sys.tables'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
```

So: Use `NVARCHAR(100)`

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(100)
SET @SQL = 'SELECT TOP 1 * FROM sys.tables'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: When i used Nvarchar the @SQL trimmed and became not completed i have to use Varchar instead of.

Comment: It gets truncated because of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371383/for-nvarcharmax-i-am-only-getting-4000-characters-in-tsql/1371584#1371584