# Calling an API from SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Calling an API from ASP.NET Web Form is very easy.

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
string urlData = wc.DownloadString("http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/sssss/getResponse.do?ID=testing");
```

But can we call an API from SQL Server stored procedure.

If yes then how can we call an API from a SQL Server stored procedure and how can we get API response?

Comment: You can do that inside of [CLR Stored Proc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094(SQL.100).aspx)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Please see [a link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1904724.aspx?Calling+a+Web+Service+from+T+SQL+Stored+Procedure+using+MSXML) for more details.

```
Declare @Object as Int;
Declare @ResponseText as Varchar(8000);

Code Snippet
Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get',
                 'http://www.webservicex.com/stockquote.asmx/GetQuote?symbol=MSFT', --Your Web Service Url (invoked)
                 'false'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT

Select @ResponseText

Exec sp_OADestroy @Object
```

Comment: Hi, this code is not working when trying to call an ASP.NET Web API endpoint. It accepts JSON. How can I change this code to make it work?

Comment: @Bat_Programmer, what issue are you facing?

Comment: e.g I want to call an API that needs for `USERID` and `API KEY`( as password)

Comment: An auth data can be passed in different way like through HTTP request header(s) of body. It depends from HTTP Service that you are going to call/use. to set HTTP (Authorization) header you can try to add following code before 'send' method: `Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'setRequestHeader', 'Authorization', 'header value like token'`. To set body you can pass content into 'send' method like following:  `Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send' , 'body content'`

Answer (score 44):

I worked so much, I hope my effort might help you out.

Just paste this into your SSMS and press F5:

```
Declare @Object as Int;
DECLARE @hr  int
Declare @json as table(Json_Table nvarchar(max))

Exec @hr=sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0', @Object OUT;
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @Object
Exec @hr=sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get',
                 'http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json];area[name=%22Auckland%22]-%3E.a;(node(area.a)[amenity=cinema];way(area.a)[amenity=cinema];rel(area.a)[amenity=cinema];);out;', --Your Web Service Url (invoked)
                 'false'
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @Object
Exec @hr=sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @Object
Exec @hr=sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @json OUTPUT
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @Object

INSERT into @json (Json_Table) exec sp_OAGetProperty @Object, 'responseText'
-- select the JSON string
select * from @json
-- Parse the JSON string
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON((select * from @json), N'$.elements')
WITH (   
      [type] nvarchar(max) N'$.type'   ,
      [id]   nvarchar(max) N'$.id',
      [lat]   nvarchar(max) N'$.lat',
      [lon]   nvarchar(max) N'$.lon',
      [amenity]   nvarchar(max) N'$.tags.amenity',
      [name]   nvarchar(max) N'$.tags.name'     
)
EXEC sp_OADestroy @Object
```

This query will give you 3 results:

**1**. Catch the error in case something goes wrong (don't panic, it will always show you an error above 4000 characters because [NVARCHAR(MAX) can only store till 4000 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371383/for-nvarcharmax-i-am-only-getting-4000-characters-in-tsql/1371584#1371584))

**2**. Put the JSON into a string (which is what we want)

**3**. BONUS: parse the JSON and nicely store the data into a table (how cool is that?)

[image]

Comment: can kerb auth be added to this?

Comment: @JoeRod, do you want to download data from Kerberos API?

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani I want to authenticate to the API endpoint with kerberos

Comment: I don't get it, maybe you are searching for this? https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/configuring-kerberos-authentication

Comment: Thanks for the bonus JSON parsing

Comment: Could you please elaborate on result 1 (always having Error 0x80042725)? I don't understand how the link provided is related.

Comment: @LuisFernandoCantu, Try to retrieve a JSON below 4000, you will see that the error goes away. In the example I'm retrieving all cinemas in Auckland, try to retrieve them from a small town.

Comment: I'm dealing with the issue of having only a limit of 100 records showing up per call. How can I write a loop to grab all records? the OPENJSON fails because my current loop creates three rows in my JSON table.

Comment: @AnthonyJ, open a new question on StackOverflow, mention me in the comment and I will try out to run your code. Is the API a public API that I can reach or something internal? 100 is a peculiar number, are you sure there is no pagination in the code?

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani I figured out my issue. The API had a limit of 100 so I just created a while loop in SQL and changed the Offset until all records were returned! thanks again your example was exactly what I needed.  Another good thing to note, is that if your OPENJSON table has more than one row you have to do a CROSS APPLY or it will fail.

Comment: Thank you @AnthonyJ, I will write a blog post as soon as I have time as there is a new feature in Azure SQL Database that allows to query REST API

Answer (score 16):

Screams in to the void - just "no" don't do it. This is a dumb idea.

Integrating with external data sources is what SSIS is for, or write a dot net application/service which queries the box and makes the API calls.

Writing CLR code to enable a SQL process to call web-services is the sort of thing that can bring a SQL box to its knees if done badly - imagine putting the the CLR function in a view somewhere - later someone else comes along not knowing what you've donem and joins on that view with a million row table - suddenly your SQL box is making a million individual webapi calls.

The whole idea is insane.

This doing sort of thing is the reason that enterprise DBAs dont' trust developers.

CLR is the kind of great power, which brings great responsibility, and the above is an abuse of it.

Comment: I also think that it does not separate the code base well, and also make you still need to set the code in two locations. Maybe I am old school and wrong, but I think it should be separated out into the C# web service calling app, unless this is done on a minimal levle.

Comment: "[Doing] this sort of thing is the reason that enterprise DBAs don't trust developers" - As both a DBA and a Lead Developer I agree with this statement!

Comment: I would like to pitch my use case. We are working with ADF and trying to check an API response.

Answer (score 6):

I think it would be easier using this CLR Stored procedure  [SQL-APIConsumer](https://github.com/geral2/SQL-APIConsumer):

```
 exec [dbo].[APICaller_POST]
     @URL = 'http://localhost:5000/api/auth/login'
    ,@BodyJson = '{"Username":"gdiaz","Password":"password"}'
```

It has multiple procedures that allows you calling API that required a parameters and even passing multiples headers and tokens authentications.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Today there is an easier way to call a REST endpoint from Azure SQL database (support for SQL Server and Azure SQL MI will come in future), thanks to the newly introduced system stored procedure `sp_invoke_external_rest_endpoint`:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-invoke-external-rest-endpoint-transact-sql

for example:

```sql
DECLARE @ret INT, @response NVARCHAR(MAX);

EXEC @ret = sp_invoke_external_rest_endpoint
  @url = N'https://<APP_NAME>.azurewebsites.net/api/<FUNCTION_NAME>?key1=value1',
  @headers = N'{"header1":"value_a", "header2":"value2", "header1":"value_b"}',
  @payload = N'{"some":{"data":"here"}}',
  @response = @response OUTPUT;

SELECT @ret AS ReturnCode, @response AS Response;
```

Comment: I followed your official Microsoft documentation, no matter the API (https://apipheny.io/free-api/) I always receive the error `Connections to the domain api.website.org are not allowed.`.

Comment: The documentation specifies that only a set of allow-listed domains can be called (for security reasons).

Answer (score 1):

Simple SQL triggered API call without building a code project

I know this is far from perfect or architectural purity, but I had a customer with a short term, critical need to integrate with a third party product via an immature API (no wsdl)
I basically needed to call the API when a database event occurred. 
I was given basic call info - URL, method, data elements and Token, but no wsdl or other start to import into a code project. All recommendations and solutions seemed start with that import.

I used the ARC (Advanced Rest Client) Chrome extension and JaSON to test the interaction with the Service from a browser and refine the call. 
That gave me the tested, raw call structure and response and let me play with the API quickly. From there, I started trying to generate the wsdl or xsd from the json using online conversions but decided that was going to take too long to get working, so I found cURL (clouds part, music plays). cURL allowed me to send the API calls to a local manager from anywhere. I then broke a few more design rules and built a trigger that queued the DB events and a SQL stored procedure and scheduled task to pass the parameters to cURL and make the calls.
I initially had the trigger calling XP_CMDShell (I know, booo) but didn't like the transactional implications or security issues, so switched to the Stored Procedure method.

In the end, DB insert matching the API call case triggers write to Queue table with parameters for API call
Stored procedure run every 5 seconds runs Cursor to pull each Queue table entry, send the XP_CMDShell call to the bat file with parameters
Bat file contains Curl call with parameters inserted sending output to logs.
Works well.

Again, not perfect, but for a tight timeline, and a system used short term, and that can be closely monitored to react to connectivity and unforeseen issues, it worked.

Hope that helps someone struggling with limited API info get a solution going quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using a CLR user defined function, if you already know how to program in C#, then the code would be;

```
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Net;

public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
{
 [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
 public static SqlString http(SqlString url)
 {
  var wc = new WebClient();
  var html = wc.DownloadString(url.Value);
  return new SqlString (html);
 }
}
```

And here's installation instructions; https://blog.dotnetframework.org/2019/09/17/make-a-http-request-from-sqlserver-using-a-clr-udf/

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Query `select * from openjson ...` works only with SQL version 2016 and higher. Need the SQL compatibility mode 130.