# How to call web API in MS SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table their are many records with email address column and i am using web api to verify email id is valid or not.
Is it possible to call via **MS SQL stored procedure**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [calling an api from sql server stored-procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22067593/calling-an-api-from-sql-server-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following sp

```
    Declare @Object as Int;
    Declare @ResponseText as Varchar(8000);


    Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
    Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get',
                 'http://your-api-address', --Your Web Service Url (invoked)
                 'false'
    Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'
    Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT

    Select @ResponseText

    Exec sp_OADestroy @Object
```

Answer (score 3):

There are almost no circumstances in which this kind of thing is a good idea. Wouldn't it be better to validate your email addresses *before* they get into the table?

As far as bad ideas go, a CLR stored procedure would be one option, as would the `sp_OACreate` stuff pasted from another stackoverflow question, but surely this kind of thing is better done *outside* the database?

Why not store the "raw" email addresses in a "staging" environment somewhere - possibly another table in your database, then create the validation processes elsewhere, maybe in a Powershell script, a .Net program, or some other kind of environment where calling a web service is trivially easy? This way you can figure out whether an address is valid as you are writing it, and then take appropriate action (don't write it? set some kind of flag?).