# REST in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, rest, t-sql

I'm not sure why I'm having such a hard time finding an answer without asking.

I have SQL Server 2016. Trying to figure out how to call a REST web service from a Procedure. Do I use OLE Automation Procedures? `MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp`? Or is there something built in? I would rather not use CLR.

Comment: Calling a web service from a stored procedure is highly unorthodox. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: for a notification

Comment: Also try https://stackoverflow.com/a/22107134/15393

Comment: Well that is a vague explanation.

Comment: I have to notify a service of an action.

Comment: When you have to start using sp_OACreate it is a sign that you are trying to do something in a way that should be reconsidered. This is exactly the kind of situation where CLR is the obvious choice.

Comment: Send a message to a service broker queue that is read by an external service (written in a language of your choice) that makes the call for you. Overkill? Possibly, depending on your scenario. More scalable and reliable? Very much so.

Comment: Calling REST services, sending notifications,  is the job of external services, scheduled jobs, web applications, SSIS scripts. It's not the job of the database. External services are **SLOW** compared to the database. Calling them will result in increased locking and performance degradation. That's why you can't find any solution except "Don't Do It"

Comment: If you want to send notifications based on data, create an SSIS package that reads the relevant data and sens the notifications, then schedule it to run as often as required.

Comment: @MotKohn as for notifying services of actions, the originator of the action should do that - that's the web application or service that called the database in the first place