# SSMS: import data from REST call

Tags: json, sql-server, rest, t-sql, ssms

I want to see if I can import data to MSSQL from a REST call to a URL. I would like to reuse this code for an hypothetic stored procedure in the future. This just wants so be a proof of concept.

This URL has some JSON that I can use for my experiment:

http://api.plos.org/search?q=title:DNA

I check if the URL returns some JSON with Postman:

[image]
All good.

I now follow [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22067593/calling-an-api-from-sql-server-stored-procedure) that tells me how to structure the call and this is my code:

```
DECLARE @Object AS INT;
DECLARE @ResponseText AS nvarchar(max);

EXEC sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'GET','http://api.plos.org/search?q=title:DNA', 'false'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT
SELECT @ResponseText
EXEC sp_OADestroy @Object
```

But unfortunately it returns me a `NULL` column.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Is there anyone out there which has ever arrived to make a REST call through SSMS?

Comment: Please don't do that! Especially not COM and the ancient MSXML2 classes that came with Windows 98. Either create a separate application eg in C# using HttpClient or a custom source in SSIS using a C# script component.

Comment: Thank you @PanagiotisKanavos, please understand that this is a Proof Of Concept. I just want to know why I cannot retrieve the JSON. Of course is a bad approach and no one should ever do this

Comment: BTW, what should I use instead of `MSXML2`?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I found an alternative to `MSXML2`, it's `WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1` and it comes straight from 2018

Comment: Not really. The problem is that you are using sp_OAxxx in the first place, when there's no need to do so. You *still* need to check the status code of the response.

Comment: As for `WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1` it was released with  [Windows Server 2003](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winhttp/winhttprequest#requirements)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, you are right. Suggest me what DLL I should use and I will write the query. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was the problem, on line 3:

1. `NVARCHAR(MAX)` can handle only 4000 characters
2. `VARCHAR(MAX)` can handle only 4000 characters
3. `VARCHAR(8000)` can handle 8000 characters

So if I try to query an URL that return less data everything is fine:

```
DECLARE @obj AS INT
DECLARE @Uri AS NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @Response AS VARCHAR(8000)

SET @Uri = 'http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=area[name="Nelson"]->.a;(node(area.a)[amenity=cinema];way(area.a)[amenity=cinema];rel(area.a)[amenity=cinema];);out;'
EXEC sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp.3.0', @obj OUT
EXEC sp_OAMethod @obj, 'open', NULL, 'GET', @Uri, false
EXEC sp_OAMethod @obj, 'send'
EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @obj, 'ResponseText', @Response OUTPUT

SELECT @Response [response] 
EXEC sp_OADestroy @obj
```

[image]

But the problem still persists above 8000 characters.

There was space for another question, if you want to dig further [follow my next question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52588498/ssms-and-sp-oamethod-is-there-a-data-type-greater-than-varchar8000?noredirect=1#comment92112463_52588498)

Comment: That's still a bad way to make HTTP calls. The first problem is `sp_OAxxx` itself. You *still* don't check the status code, which means you won't know what happend. You use the *WRONG* text type - HTTP responses are predominantly UTF8. This means you'll get mangled text if you get any non-US characters in the response

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I wrote another reply here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22067593/calling-an-api-from-sql-server-stored-procedure  and, yes, as you can see in that post I can catch the error. How can I change the text type if UTF8 is not good? I don't see in my query what manage the UTF8. Thank you

Comment: Now compare it with the OP's question. Dozens of lines that don't even do what the two-liner does. There's a reason sp_OAxxx isn't used and SQLCLR was introduced instead. BTW in case of error both answers will leak COM objects which are *NOT* garbage-collected. COM objects are reference counted. If you don't call `sp_OADestroy` they'll remain alive, probably until the service restarts. You need a `TRY .. CATCH` block

Comment: To put it another way, people that worked with `sp_OA` in the past abandoned it very quickly once SQLCLR came out. It creates a lot of problems, weakens security for *no* benefit

Comment: You convinced me @PanagiotisKanavos, I will try to use SQLCLR. BTW, fun fact: `WinHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1` cannot read japanese but `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0` can apparently parse UTF-8 because I see the character in my database

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use SSIS(SQL Server Integration Services) instead SSMS.
you can take a look on the following link:

[Reference Link 1](https://zappysys.com/blog/loading-data-from-rest-api-to-sql-server-in-ssis/)

[Reference Link 2](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/139022/consume-rest-api-with-ssis)

Comment: Thank you @Mohammad, I didn't know I could do that through SSIS. It is definitely the right approach. BTW, I'm don't need to actually query any URL, I just want to understand what is wrong with that code. Is just an experiment, a Proof Of Concept.