# SSMS and sp_OAMethod: is there a Data Type greater than VARCHAR(8000)?

Tags: rest, api, ssms, sqldatatypes, varcharmax

Calling a REST service through SSMS is indeed not a great idea.

BTW since Microsoft created the [Stored Procedure sp_OAMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-oamethod-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and even Phil Factor from Red Gate [show us how to use it](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/importing-json-web-services-applications-sql-server/) I wanted to give it a go.

I wanted to import some data from OpenStreetMap directly into MSSQL, so I copy a good query [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22067593/calling-an-api-from-sql-server-stored-procedure) and I adapt it to my whish.

In this example I'm returning all Cinemas in **Nelson**:

```
DECLARE @obj AS INT
DECLARE @Uri AS NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @Response AS VARCHAR(8000)

SET @Uri = 'http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=area[name="Nelson"]->.a;(node(area.a)[amenity=cinema];way(area.a)[amenity=cinema];rel(area.a)[amenity=cinema];);out;'
EXEC sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp.3.0', @obj OUT
EXEC sp_OAMethod @obj, 'open', NULL, 'GET', @Uri, false
EXEC sp_OAMethod @obj, 'send'
EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @obj, 'ResponseText', @Response OUTPUT

SELECT @Response [response] 
EXEC sp_OADestroy @obj
```

Nice and easy, I can see the REST call response in Postman as well as in SSMS:

[image]

Problem starts when I try to retrieve all Cinemas from a bigger city like **Auckland**:

```
DECLARE @obj AS INT
DECLARE @Uri AS NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @Response AS VARCHAR(8000)

SET @Uri = 'http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=area[name="Auckland"]->.a;(node(area.a)[amenity=cinema];way(area.a)[amenity=cinema];rel(area.a)[amenity=cinema];);out;'
EXEC sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp.3.0', @obj OUT
EXEC sp_OAMethod @obj, 'open', NULL, 'GET', @Uri, false
EXEC sp_OAMethod @obj, 'send'
EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @obj, 'ResponseText', @Response OUTPUT

SELECT @Response [response] 
EXEC sp_OADestroy @obj
```

The REST call is retrieving more data and the variable `@Response AS VARCHAR(8000)` cannot hold all the data:

[image]

Of course I tried to use `DECLARE @Response AS VARCHAR(MAX)` but this won't help neither.

Shouldn't `VARCHAR(MAX)` hold **65,535 characters** and till **2GB** of data?

What should I use instead?

Is there a way to split data and concatenate later?

**EDIT:** I think I'm getting closer: I can use OPENJSON [this way](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MwgzCWAASko&ab_channel=BertWagner), but I still don't know how to structure the query... any help would be appreciated

Comment: I would use SQLCLR, not sp_OA%. sp_OA is simply not safe to use

Comment: Thank you but this is not the point: even using `SQLCLR` the problem remains because I cannot store all the result inside the datatype `VARCHAR(MAX)`. The maximum stored value for `VARCHAR(MAX)` is 4000 characters but I have 6000. Do you know a bigger datatype?

Comment: VARCHAR(MAX) *is* 2GB. varchar(n) is max 8000. varchar(8000) is different to varchar(max) in storage and some other behaviours. If you want more than 8000 characters in a column or variable, use VARCHAR(MAX)

Comment: Man, I'm telling you that VARCHAR(MAX) cannot store more then 8000 characters. Try out yourself `DECLARE @str varchar(max)
SET @str = REPLICATE('A', 4000) + REPLICATE('B', 4000) + REPLICATE('C', 4000)
PRINT LEN(@str)`

Comment: You're doing it *wrong*. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1371584/27535 for why. If you still disagree, then contact go to Microsoft guthub and update the documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm clapping the hands to myself.

I admit, it's a nightmare solution but it get things done. The solution was to set:

`Declare @Response as table(Json_Table nvarchar(max))`

This way I created a table with a data type which has `nvarchar(max)` and now yes, it can hold **65,535 characters** and till **2GB** of data.

```
Declare @Object as Int;
DECLARE @hr  int
Declare @Response as table(Json_Table nvarchar(max))

Exec @hr=sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0', @Object OUT;
Exec @hr=sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get',
                 'http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json];area[name="Auckland"]->.a;(node(area.a)[amenity=cinema];way(area.a)[amenity=cinema];rel(area.a)[amenity=cinema];);out;', --Your Web Service Url (invoked)
                 'false'
Exec @hr=sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'
Exec @hr=sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @Response OUTPUT

INSERT into @Response (Json_Table) exec sp_OAGetProperty @Object, 'responseText'

select * from @Response

EXEC sp_OADestroy @Object
```

Please post if you find a better solution, it will be much appreciated.

Comment: Thank you, this is truly hideous but it saved me an hour having to re-write ancient code into a CLR

Comment: Awsome you saved a lot of time man, God Bless you

Comment: It's 2023 and this saved me from CLR.  My only comment is that if you get a NULL back when you know you should get data, try changing from 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0' to simply 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP'  This could be because I'm on a 2016 SSMS but running under compatibility level 2008R2.  Again, THANK YOU

Comment: Thank you @fldavem , if you liked my reply you will love this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22067593/calling-an-api-from-sql-server-stored-procedure

Answer (score 1):

Wrong code:

```
DECLARE @str varchar(max)
SET @str = REPLICATE('A', 4000) + REPLICATE('B', 4000) + REPLICATE('C', 4000)
PRINT LEN(@str)
```

From [REPLICATE in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replicate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) docs

> If string_expression is not of type varchar(max) or nvarchar(max),
>   REPLICATE truncates the return value at 8,000 bytes. To return values
>   greater than 8,000 bytes, string_expression must be explicitly cast to
>   the appropriate large-value data type.

Correct code:

```
DECLARE @str varchar(max)
DECLARE @seed varchar(max) = 'A'

SET @str = REPLICATE(@seed, 4000) + REPLICATE(@seed, 4000) + REPLICATE(@seed, 4000)
PRINT LEN(@str)

--12000
```

For other answers, see [For Nvarchar(Max) I am only getting 4000 characters in TSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371383/for-nvarcharmax-i-am-only-getting-4000-characters-in-tsql/1371584#1371584)

Comment: Boom. you gave a great idea. I will label it as the answer if I cannot find something better. Thank you for your help