# SSMS: OPENJSON works but not with direct REST call

Tags: json, sql-server, rest, open-json

Following [this article](https://bertwagner.com/2018/09/18/extracting-json-values-longer-than-4000-characters/) I'm trying to implement a query that could retrieve data from a REST call and parse the JSON with OPENJSON.

I call [this URL](http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json];area[name=%22Nelson%22]-%3E.a;(node(area.a)[amenity=cinema];way(area.a)[amenity=cinema];rel(area.a)[amenity=cinema];);out;) with Postman to check if the data are alright:

[image]

The data are there.

I copy paste the JSON and I test my call on SSMS:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'{
    "version": 0.6,
    "generator": "Overpass API 0.7.55.4 3079d8ea",
    "osm3s": {
        "timestamp_osm_base": "2018-10-04T10:07:02Z",
        "timestamp_areas_base": "2018-10-04T09:02:02Z",
        "copyright": "The data included in this document is from www.openstreetmap.org. The data is made available under ODbL."
    },
    "elements": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "id": 501591237,
            "lat": 49.4943882,
            "lon": -117.2910343,
            "tags": {
                "amenity": "cinema",
                "name": "Civic Theatre",
                "website": "http://civictheatre.ca"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "id": 2293276829,
            "lat": -41.2709865,
            "lon": 173.2842196,
            "tags": {
                "amenity": "cinema",
                "name": "Cinema 6"
            }
        }
    ]
}';



SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@json, N'$.elements')
WITH (   
      [type] nvarchar(max) N'$.type'   ,
      [id]   nvarchar(max) N'$.id',
      [lat]   nvarchar(max) N'$.lat',
      [lon]   nvarchar(max) N'$.lon',
      [amenity]   nvarchar(max) N'$.tags.amenity',
      [name]   nvarchar(max) N'$.tags.name'

)
```

All good, is working: my query can parse the JSON.

[image]

I now follow [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22067593/calling-an-api-from-sql-server-stored-procedure) that shows me how to make a REST call **within** SSMS and I try to retrieve the data of the same URL and see them on-the-fly into SSMS:

```
Declare @Object as Int;
Declare @json as nvarchar(max);


Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get',
                 'http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json];area[name=%22Nelson%22]-%3E.a;(node(area.a)[amenity=cinema];way(area.a)[amenity=cinema];rel(area.a)[amenity=cinema];);out;', --Your Web Service Url (invoked)
                 'false'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @json OUTPUT

select @json

SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@json, N'$.elements')
WITH (   
      [type] nvarchar(max) N'$.type'   ,
      [id]   nvarchar(max) N'$.id',
      [lat]   nvarchar(max) N'$.lat',
      [lon]   nvarchar(max) N'$.lon',
      [amenity]   nvarchar(max) N'$.tags.amenity',
      [name]   nvarchar(max) N'$.tags.name'

)

Exec sp_OADestroy @Object
```

Ouch! Is not working!

[image]

Why the data are empty? `Declare @json as nvarchar(max);` was working in the previous query. why is not working any more?

If I put `Declare @json as varchar(8000);` it works only because I'm retrieving less than 8000 characters but I cannot work this way.

[image]

If I'm not wrong `OPENJSON` was developed exactly to avoid such problem and load till 2GB of data.

I want to use `nvarchar(max)` and load a lot of data. This is the whole point of using `OPENJSON`.

Comment: SSMS is the client tool, it has nothing to do with the queries. OPENJSON has nothing to do with how its input is generated. And `sp_OAMethod` is *not* a good way to make HTTP calls. Apart from the risk of creating orphaned objects, it can't pass headers or handle responses. It was use *before* SQL Server 2005. If you have to make HTTP calls use SQLCLR at least. Better yet, make the calls from the client, not the database

Comment: BTW the output means that nothing was returned from that HTTP call, not that OPENJSON failed. If an HTTP call fails the server returns a Status code and description that explain what's wrong, eg 401 is Unauthorized, 404 Not Found etc. There's no response text in these cases

Comment: You need to retrieve the [status](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms767625(v%3Dvs.85)) property, eg with `sp_OAMethod @Object, 'status'` and [statusText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms759127(v%3dvs.85)) to see why the call failed.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, you can POST `body` and `headers`. Unfortunately I cannot drop DLLs on the customer machine. I know is wrong but sp_OAMethod get the work done in seconds and is the only thing I can use

Comment: As said, if I substitute `nvarchar(max)` with `varchar(8000)` I see the JSON in SSMS. Thank you for the tip, I used `sp_OAMethod @Object, 'status'` and yes, I have a 200. So the call is good. `varchar(8000)` can hold the JSON because can hold 8000 characters but `nvarchar(MAX)` can only hold 4000 characters.

Comment: If so it means that `OPENJSON` can only read and store JSON till 2GB size from a file but not from a REST call and SQLCLR will fail as well because there is no data type that can store more than 8000 characters in MSSQL. Which is kind of awkward

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I'm not the only one: it seems SQL Server cannot do REST call after 8000 characters: https://blog.dotnetframework.org/2010/09/01/make-a-http-request-from-sql-server/ . Odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done.

Thank you so much @PanagiotisKanavos for the suggestion of the `status` in order to catch the error.

The solution was to use `Declare @json as table(Json_Table nvarchar(max))` and store the JSON into a table instead of a variable. **It now can store 2GB!!!**

```
Declare @Object as Int;
DECLARE @hr  int
Declare @json as table(Json_Table nvarchar(max))

Exec @hr=sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0', @Object OUT;
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @Object
Exec @hr=sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get',
                 'http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json];area[name="Auckland"]->.a;(node(area.a)[amenity=cinema];way(area.a)[amenity=cinema];rel(area.a)[amenity=cinema];);out;', --Your Web Service Url (invoked)
                 'false'
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @Object
Exec @hr=sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @Object
Exec @hr=sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @json OUTPUT
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @Object

INSERT into @json (Json_Table) exec sp_OAGetProperty @Object, 'responseText'

SELECT * FROM OPENJSON((select * from @json), N'$.elements')
WITH (   
      [type] nvarchar(max) N'$.type'   ,
      [id]   nvarchar(max) N'$.id',
      [lat]   nvarchar(max) N'$.lat',
      [lon]   nvarchar(max) N'$.lon',
      [amenity]   nvarchar(max) N'$.tags.amenity',
      [name]   nvarchar(max) N'$.tags.name'     
)
EXEC sp_OADestroy @Object
```

[image]

Is this the right way to get things done?

Hell no! I shouldn't use `sp_OAMethod` and I should use `SQLCLR` instead, or any other external process written in `Python`, `PowerShell`, `VB`, `C#`, etc...

But, you know, I should also drink less beer and buy less bacon but...YOLO, whatever works... just do it.

Thanks to this I can now create a stored procedure that makes a REST call and automatically save data into SQL Server. I hunted the solution for days and I finally found the answer [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/103973/how-do-i-use-a-stored-procedure-in-sql-server-2014-to-call-a-external-xml-source).

I hope this will help, I see there are a few hundred people searching for this reply out there.