# Calling a REST API from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am using the following code to call my REST API from SQL Server but I am getting empty string in the response message. I put a breakpoint in visual studio on getTravelerInfoById method but it is also not triggered. Can you please check and let me know what am I doing wrong?

```
DECLARE @URL NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'https://localhost:7128/api/TravelerBase/getTravelerInfoById';
DECLARE @Object AS INT;
DECLARE @ResponseText AS VARCHAR(8000);
DECLARE @Body AS VARCHAR(8000) =
'{
   "var1": "2024-03-16 16:56:59",
   "var2": "+0200",
   "var3": "856"
}'
EXEC sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'post',
                 @URL,
                 'false'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'Content-Type', 'application/json'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send', null, @body
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT

SELECT @ResponseText As 'ResponseText'

IF CHARINDEX('false',(SELECT @ResponseText)) > 0
BEGIN
 SELECT @ResponseText As 'Message'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
 SELECT @ResponseText As 'customer Details'
END
EXEC sp_OADestroy @Object
```

I enabled the procedures as below:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO  
sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO
```

I tried a GET api https://localhost:7128/api/TravelerBase/getVersion as well but it is also not triggered.

I also tried the following simple API that gives version number but its also giving empty string.

```
Declare @Object as Int;
Declare @ResponseText as Varchar(8000);

--Code Snippet
Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get',
                 'https://vps-7034f481.vps.ovh.net/simat/simatapi/api/TravelerBase/getVersion', --Your Web Service Url (invoked)
                 'false'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT

Select @ResponseText

Exec sp_OADestroy @Object
```

Thanks.

Comment: Calling any API from within SQL Server is a positively horrible idea ... don't do it, stop wasting time on this - calling API's belongs in a **service layer** of an app - shouldn't be done from within the database engine....

Comment: Not to state the obvious, just checking, have you tried the REST Api outside the stored procedure? With that out the way, this has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22067593/calling-an-api-from-sql-server-stored-procedure.

Comment: @DouadyRabbit I edited my post and I pasted a simple code to get version number as suggested in the post the you referred. Its again giving me empty string.